# ¿como crear objetos con nombres distintos automaticamente?

Tags: java, poo, bucle-for, objeto

Mi pregunta sería como hacer para crear objetos con nombres diferentes, cada vez que se ejecute el bucle, ponga un nombre distinto al objeto.

Aquí está mi idea y mi intento:

```
        int nAlumnos = random.nextInt(10)+15;


        for(int i=0;i<nAlumnos;i++){
            alumnos "alumno"+i = new alumnos();
        }
```

Comment: Creo que no se puede hacer. Pero puedes añadir a una lista los objetos alumnos.      Por ej fuera del bucle introduces List<Alumnos> listAlumnos = new ArrayList().   Dentro del bucle haces listAlumnos.add(new alumno()). Esto te creará un nuevo alumno por cada iteracion. Luego juegas con las esa lista y ya no necesitas nombres del objeto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿Has pensado en simplemente usar una lista de alumnos?
Por cierto, las clases deben empezar por mayúscula y te recomiendo llamarla Alumno y no Alumnos, ya que ese plural indicaría que hay varios alumnos por objeto.

```java
List<Alumno> clase = new ArrayList<>();
int nAlumnos = random.nextInt(10) + 15;

for(int i = 0; i < nAlumnos; i++) {
    clase.add(new Alumno("Nombre" + i); 
}

Alumno a = clase.get(9); //tengo el décimo alumno creado
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se realiza es crear un objeto que tenga la propiedad nombre, de esta forma puedes identificar un objeto alumno con nombre diferente.

Crea tu clase `alumno`:

public class alumno {

```
private int id;
private String nombre;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

}

De esta forma puedes generar objetos con diferente nombre:

```
alumno a = new alumno();
a.setNombre("Hugo Oliva Romero");
...    
a = new alumno();
a.setNombre("StackoverFlow");
```

Para generar objetos con diferente nombre, puedes guardar estos objetos con diferente nombre en un `List` y posteriormente consultarlos con base en su índice:

```
  List<alumno> alumnos = new ArrayList<>();
    Random random = new Random();
    int nAlumnos = random.nextInt(10)+15;         
    for(int i=0;i< nAlumnos;i++){
       alumno a = new alumno();
        a.setNombre("nombre " + i);
        alumnos.add(a); //Agrega alumno
    }
    

    //Consultamos alumnos        
    for(int j=0; j< alumnos.size(); j++){
      System.out.println(alumnos.get(j).getNombre());
    }
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
nombre 0
nombre 1
nombre 2
nombre 3
nombre 4
nombre 5
```

Answer (score 0):

me parece que una buena opción, es optar por usar un Map de la siguiente forma:

```
int nAlumnos = random.nextInt(10)+15;
Map<String, Alumnos> alumnos = new HashMap();

for( int i = 0; i < nAlumnos; i++ ) {
    alumnos.put( "alumno" + i, new Alumnos() );
}
```

Puedes si es necesario, pasarle el nombre al constructor:

```
alumnos.put( "alumno" + i, new Alumnos( "alumno" + i ) );
```

O ir más allá y crear un array de nombres, y...

```
String nombres[] = { "Carlos", "Antonio", "Pepe" };

for( int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++ ) {
    alumnos.put( nombres[ i ], new Alumnos( nombres[ i ] ) );
}
```

Luego para obtener un alumno:

```
Alumnos alumno = alumnos.get( "alumno1" );
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.